# Start-ServiceFabricPartitionDataLoss : Operation timed out

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When I run this command it never completes.

```
Start-ServiceFabricPartitionDataLoss -DataLossMode FullDataLoss -ServiceName "fabric:/CompanyInfo/PartyActorService" -OperationId d3f12b09-6a90-4745-a4fc-3f92149a7410 -PartitionId 6db8c4e7-d27a-4918-8111-36faeae7afee
```

It will result in

```
Start-ServiceFabricPartitionDataLoss : Operation timed out.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-ServiceFabricPartitionDataLoss -DataLossMode FullDataLoss -Serv ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Start-ServiceFa
   bricPartitionDataLoss], TimeoutException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartDataLossCommandErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartDataLoss
```

I'm trying to test my backup in my local environment. I copied the partition id form the Service fabric explorer.

Get-ServiceFabricPartitionDataLossProgress also result in a timeout.

Since powershell was not working for me I tried it via code. But with the same result

```
fabricClient.TestManager.StartPartitionDataLossAsync(operationId, partitionSelector, DataLossMode.FullDataLoss, CancellationToken)
```

Is there any way to get more debug information why it goes wrong?

Comment: Haishi Bai wrote this in his book "Programming Microsoft Azure Service Fabric": To hook up your custom onDataLossEventhandler, you need to override the CreateReliableStateManager method of the StatefulService class. But I cannot find this method.

Comment: did you make any progress with this?

Comment: No, i didn't make any progress on this..

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch cluster mode to 5 Node